# Flask run isn't running and gives me error

Tags: python, flask, flask-mysql

im trying to run flask and when i run
flask run

I get this error

```
(snoop) ether@ether:~/Documents/loginsystem$ flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

I have done

```
Run command: set FLASK_APP=main.py
Run command: set FLASK_DEBUG=1
Run command: flask run
```

but that doesn't change anything on the error

Im using this tutorial for a login system
https://codeshack.io/login-system-python-flask-mysql/

Comment: Could you show what your working directory looks like?

Comment: Is not that setting environment variable before activating the virtualenv is bad idea?

Comment: /home/ether/Documents/loginsystem

Comment: @redbulll please update your question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try exporting the variable instead of just setting it ?

`export FLASK_APP=main.py`

and not

`set FLASK_APP=main.py`

Comment: i run export and than flask run- the server is running but i already have another error because it says 404 not found- but server is running in console